# How to make this URL box search machine target in a new _blank window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, target

How do I make this search word of a search page to open in a separate `_blank` window using the URL string? Right now it works, but only as a _self targeted and not as in a new window as a _blank.

I need this to show the result in a blank new window.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function GoToURL()
{
    var URLis;
    URLis = document.URLframe.u.value
    {
        var location=("https://SearchMyPageA.com/?q=" + URLis + "&ia=meanings");
        this.location.href = location;
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="URLframe" method="post">
<input value="test" type="text" name="u" size="70">
<input type="button" onclick="GoToURL(this)" value=" Search ">
</form>
```

**NOTE:** I would rather want a JavaScript answer, but if there is no JavaScript answer to this, then a query answer I guess will work too.

**The COOL part:** This is the cool part of this code. This works with almost any search machine on the internet with a little bit of tweak in the values and in the JavaScript to fit the amount if search boxes we used. The only thing you need is to type test on the original page and see how the URL looks on that one and then replace the word URL address and the end text wile the `+ URLis +` stands for what ever you type in the search box instead of test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use location to open a new window. Try `window.open()` with `_blank` as the second parameter instead.

```js
function GoToURL()
{
    var URLis;
    URLis = document.URLframe.u.value
    {
        var location=("https://SearchMyPageA.com/?q=" + URLis + "&ia=meanings");

        //this.location.href = location;
        window.open(location, '_blank')
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="URLframe" id="form" method="post">
  <input value="test" type="text" name="u" size="70">
  <input type="button" onclick="GoToURL(this)" value=" Search ">
</form>
```

Comment: You know what is cool with this code now? This made now works with almost any search machine on the internet with a little bit of tweak in the values and in the JavaScript to fit the amount if search boxes we used. The only thing you need is to type test on the original page and see how the URL looks on that one and then replace the word URL address and the end text wile the `+ URLis +` stands for what ever you type in the search box instead of test.

Comment: That's really great. Thank you again for letting me know everything.

Comment: No problem. My interest in making it was to make a code that was versatile an worked with any webpage. Try it as an example with this page `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=test&ia=meanings` . Change the text `https://SearchMyPageA.com/?q=` into this `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=` and leave the end code `&ia=meanings`because by coincidence it is the same.
Or with GOOGLE for example change the beginning into this `https://www.google.com/search?q=` and at the end this `&gws_rd=cr&ei=yL3-WOKBOcbX6QTO2IiQDg`Or what ever page the same thing.

Comment: Or Bing search start code `http://www.bing.com/search?q=` and end code `&pc=cosp&ptag=C31AB901F24011&form=CONTLB&conlogo=CT3210127` and so on with any search page on the net.

Answer (score 0):

try using ...

```
window.open(
  'https://SearchMyPageA.com/?q=' + URLis + '&ia=meanings',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Comment: The problem now with your solution is that it searches for `" + URLis + "` instead of the word `test` as it is written in the box value.
I get the incorrect link: `https://SearchMyPageA.com/?q=%22%20+%20URLis%20+%20%22&ia=meanings`
Instead off this:
`https://SearchMyPageA.com/?q=test&ia=meanings` who is the correct

Comment: sorry I have now fixed the quotes. Give that a shot.

Comment: Thank you I will try it, so we know if it works or not. But I will not use it since I already got the answer for a more simple solution now. So sorry, but the more simple it is the less there is that something goes wrong on other browsers.

Comment: On the other hand your solution makes it enable to double search twice the same result and if I want to make it search different motives like we say example one for `&ia=meanings` and the other for `&ia=videos` your solution makes it possible with a bit of tweek.

Comment: But yes thank you your solution works too and also perfect. But I will now chose the sorter solution as it is less codes and more clean. But in case I want to expand some extra functions your solution is a good option.